# Better to jump between functions or pass values from function to function? C

Tags: c, function, return

I have a quick question. Is it typically better to jump between functions or pass values from function to function?

For example, in the game that I'm currently working on, with the struct `game_structure` as the struct containing all the data, would it be better to pass new game_structures between functions, or to use functions more-or-less as loops? Currently, for example, I call the function `inventory(game_structure *gs)` which loops through the inventory commands. However, when it is finished, it starts the function `game_loop(game_structure *gs);` which goes back to the game. Would it be better if I had `inventory(game_structure *gs)` return a `game_structure` to be called upon somewhere else?

But even in other cases, what is more beneficial? Jumping between loops, or returning values?

Comment: It is better to write simple easy to maintain and not-impossible to extend code. Unless this can't be done for more pressing reasons. (I have yet to find any in *my* work.)

Comment: I think it may not be a bad idea to create some kind of static data structure for this, non-local jumps destroys stack (not really, but..).

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps maintainability if the program flow is constructed in a procedural manner (if at all possible). So, calling another function at the end of a function when the caller doesn't care about the outcome of the function that was called is complicating things unnecessarily. In my code, I try to minimize unnecessary call nesting and recursion. It makes your life simpler when it comes to maintaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are doing and what programming language you are using.

In C I would err on the side of reusing the structure and avoiding doing too much recursive stuff (to avoid blowing the stack). After all, writing tight code and using little memory is the whole point of C nowadays and mallocinc stuff is really annoying too.

On the other hand, if I were programming this in Haskell I would err on the side of immutable datastructures and tons of recursion/tail-recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of stack size versus object copy, I believe.

For C in particular, pass value or reference to other functions. This not only maintain the logic but is THE right way to go in almost all cases.

If you call another function at the `return` statement, the original stack is not destroyed and a new stack for the new function is created. While doing so, during the function jump, the object will be copied or moved to the new stack for manipulation. Depend on compiler though, it is not guaranteed to be "moved", thus make this the same as passing object by value to function plus the possibility of overflow the stack.

A better practice, if you are really concerned about big object copy for multiple times, is to declare the object as a global static one within its life scope. While calling functions, pass the reference of the object around. There is one catch though. You need to be extra careful while accessing memory as the data can be unintentionally changed.